# How to ignore special characters with arrow keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript to ignore special character in textbox.
But i need to allow arrow key actions.

So, i allow

- left = 37
- up = 38
- right = 39
- down = 40

keys in my textbox.

I use the following function for this,

```
function checkKeys(event){
 // Getting the event to be triggered.
var theEvent = event || window.event;
// Getting the type of event or code.
var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

// Check with list of code and ignore holding.
// Tab, Space, Home, End, Up, Down, Left, Right...
if (key === 9 || key === 32 || key === 13 || key === 8 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40)) { //TAB was pressed
    return true;
}

// If not in list then check return with corresponding data.
key = String.fromCharCode(key);
// Return also if length is 0.
if (key.length == 0) return true;

// Finally return "false" for general keys.
return false;
}
```

but i find another issue with this keys.

- left = 37 = %
- up = 38 = &
- right = 39 = '
- down = 40 = (

The same navigation keys are same as special characters key.

What's wrong in this ?

How can i restrict to use special chars[%,&,',(] in my textbox ?

Comment: Use `event.key` or `event.shiftKey` to distinguish between them.

Comment: That's not allow action keys( like <-,->)

Comment: What "that's"?.

Comment: event.shiftKey  not allow action keys !

Comment: `event.shiftKey` does not prohibit anything, it's just an object key.